# It is difficult to implement the function to stop the wheel at the desired location using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

(I'm not good at English, so I'm posting my question through a translator. Please understand that the English sentences are not smooth as we used a translator.)

I am a student slowly studying JavaScript, CSS, and HTML.
We are implementing it so that only items with a checkmark in the checkbox on the wheel can win.
I'm writing code under the assumption that there is only one checked item. I've searched and implemented it for several days, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

I wrote the JavaScript code below, but it doesn't work as I want.

**roulette.js**

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(elem) {
   this.some(function(e, i, a) {
      if (e === elem) {
         a.splice(i, 1);
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   });
   return this;
};
Array.prototype.removeAll = function(elem) {
   this.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
      if (e === elem) {
         a.splice(i, 1);
      }
   });
   return this;
}

var colorPalette = [
   // ~~~
];
(function() {
   var startColorIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorPalette.length);
   var startColor = colorPalette[startColorIdx];
   colorPalette.remove(startColor);
   window.getColor = function(i) {
      if (i == 0) return startColor;
      return colorPalette[ Math.floor(startColorIdx + 4 * i) % colorPalette.length ];
   };
})();

var noname = 'noname';
var font = '32px Hanna';
var font2 = font; //'36px Sans-serif';
var line_color = '#37474f';
var bgColor = '#ffffff';
var pinColor = '#37474f';
var fontStrokeStyle = '#37474f';

function isChecked(item) {
   var checked = $(item).find('.item-checkbox').is(':checked');
    // Add a log to output the status of the checkbox to the console
    console.log('Item checked:', checked);
   if (checked) {
        var text = $(item).find('.item-title').text();
        var index = $(item).index();
        console.log('Item text:', text);
        console.log('Item index:', index);
    }
    return checked;
}

function DEG2RAD(degree) {
   return (degree * Math.PI) / 180;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   var $li = $('li.item');
   var $cl = $li.clone();
   window.createItem = function() {
      $('ul').append($cl.clone());
   }
});


function updateData() {

   var items = [];
   var angleSum = 0;
   var weightSum = 0;

   $('li.item').each(function(i, e) {
      var $e = $(e);
      var $title = $e.find('.item-title');
      if ($title.text()) {
         $e.removeClass('empty');
      } else {
         $e.addClass('empty');
         return;
      }
      var weight = parseFloat($e.find('.item-weight').attr('data-weight')) || 0;
      weightSum += weight;
   });
   $('li.item:not(.empty)').each(function(i, e) {
      var $e = $(e);
      
      var title = $e.find('.item-title').text();
      if (!title) {
         return;
      }
      var weight = parseFloat($e.find('.item-weight').attr('data-weight')) || 0;
      var chance = weight / weightSum;
      $e.attr('data-chance', (chance * 100).toFixed(2));

      var angle = 360 * chance;
      angleSum += angle;

      var color = getColor(i)
      items.push({
         name: title,
         angle: angle,
         angleSum: angleSum,
         color: color
      });

      $e.css('background', 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + color + ' 11%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%)');
   });

   R.Items = items;
   R.dirty = true;
   R.checkedAngle = null;
   if (R.Items.length > 0) { // Check if the array is not empty
      R.Items.forEach(function(item) {
         if (item.name === R.current) {
            R.checkedAngle = {
               start: item.angleSum - item.angle,
               end: item.angleSum
            };
         }
      });
   }
}

function cleanList() {
   var empty = [];
   $('li').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var $title = $this.find('.item-title');
      var text = $title.text().trim();
      $title.text(text);
      if (!text) {
         empty.push($this);
      }
   });

   if (empty.length === 0) {
      // create new li
      createItem();
   } else if (empty.length > 1) {
      empty.pop();
      empty.forEach(function($e) {
         $e.remove();
      });
   }
}

$(document).on('blur', '.item-title', function(evt) {
   cleanList();
   updateData();
});
$(document).on('keyup', '.item-title', function(evt) {
   updateData();
});

$(document).on('click', 'li.item', function(evt) {
   $(evt.currentTarget).find('.item-title').focus();
});

$(document).on('click', '.item-weight-add, .item-weight-sub', function(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   var $this = $(evt.currentTarget);
   var sign = $this.is('.item-weight-add') ? +1 : $this.is('.item-weight-sub') ? -1 : 0;
   var $w = $this.focus().siblings('.item-weight');
   var amount = evt.ctrlKey && !evt.shiftKey &&  evt.altKey ? 1000 :
            !evt.ctrlKey && !evt.shiftKey &&  evt.altKey ? 100 :
             evt.ctrlKey && !evt.shiftKey && !evt.altKey ? 10 :
            1;
   var w = Math.floor(Math.max(1, Math.min(9999, (parseInt($w.attr('data-weight')) || 1) + sign * amount)));
   $w.attr('data-weight', w);
   updateData();
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(evt) {
   var $target = $(evt.target);
   if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
      evt.preventDefault();
      cleanList();
      if ($target.is('.item-title')) {
         $target.blur()
         .closest('li')
         .next('li')
         .find('.item-title').focus();
      }
      if ($target.is('[contenteditable]')) {
         $target.blur();
      }
   } else if (evt.key === 'Escape') {
      if ($target.is('[contenteditable]')) {
         $target.blur();
      }
   }
});

function Roulette() {

   var R = {
      dirty: true,
      rotation: 0,
      $button: $('#roll')
   };
   window.R = R;

   function OnStart() {
      try {
         $(document.body).css('background', bgColor);
         R.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
         R.ctx = R.canvas.getContext('2d', true);
         R.size = { width: R.canvas.width, height: R.canvas.height };
         R.center = { x: R.size.width / 2 , y: R.size.height / 2 };

         window.radius = Math.min(Math.min(R.size.width, R.size.height) * 0.5 * 0.9, R.size.height / 2 - 40);

         R.bufferCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
         R.bufferCanvas.width = R.size.width;
         R.bufferCanvas.height = R.size.height;
         R.buffer = R.bufferCanvas.getContext('2d', true);
         R.buffer.textAlign='center';

         requestAnimationFrame(OnUpdate);
      } catch(e) { console.log(e); }
   }

   function OnUpdate(timestamp) {
      R.deltaTime = timestamp - (R.lastTimestamp || timestamp);

      requestAnimationFrame(OnUpdate);
      if (0 < R.deltaTime && R.deltaTime < 17) {
         return;
      }

      if (R.stopping) {
         if (Date.now() - R.stopping > 15 * 1000) {
            R.angularVelocity = 0;
            delete R.stopping;
         }
         else
         {
            // Check if the pin is within the angle range of the checked item
            if (R.checkedAngle && (R.currentAngle < R.checkedAngle.start || R.currentAngle > R.checkedAngle.end)) {
            // If not, keep rotating slowly until you get within the angle
               R.angularVelocity = Math.max(10, R.angularVelocity);
            } else {
            // If within range, roulette stops
               R.angularVelocity -= Math.max(20, Math.min(R.angularVelocity * 0.5, R.angularDamping)) * (R.deltaTime / 1000);
            }
         }
      }
      if (R.angularDamping) {
         R.angularVelocity -= Math.max(20, Math.min(R.angularVelocity * 0.5, R.angularDamping)) * (R.deltaTime / 1000);
      }
      if (R.angularVelocity <= 0) {
         R.angularVelocity = 0;
         if (R.launched && typeof R.onStop === 'function') {
            R.launched = false;
            R.onStop();
         }
      }
      if (R.angularVelocity) {
         R.rotation += R.angularVelocity * (R.deltaTime / 1000);
         while (R.rotation < 0) R.rotation += 360;
         while (R.rotation >= 360) R.rotation -= 360;
      }
      if (R.prevRotation != R.rotation) {
         R.dirty = true;
      }
      R.prevRotation = R.rotation;

      // render
      OnRender();
      R.lastTimestamp = timestamp;
   }

   function drawArc(option, name, split) {
      if (!split || (split && !name)) {
         R.buffer.save();
         R.buffer.translate(option.x, option.y);
         R.buffer.rotate(DEG2RAD(option.rotation - 90));

         R.buffer.beginPath();
         R.buffer.moveTo(0, 0);
         R.buffer.arc(0, 0, option.radius, 0, DEG2RAD(option.angle));
         R.buffer.closePath();
         R.buffer.fillStyle = option.color;
         R.buffer.fill();

         R.buffer.beginPath();
         R.buffer.arc(0, 0, option.radius, 0, DEG2RAD(option.angle));
         R.buffer.strokeStyle = window.line_color;
         R.buffer.lineWidth = 3;
         R.buffer.stroke();

         R.buffer.restore();
      }
      if (!split || (split && name)) {
         // text
         R.buffer.save();
         R.buffer.translate(option.x, option.y);
         R.buffer.rotate(DEG2RAD(option.rotation - 90 + option.angle / 2));

         R.buffer.beginPath();
         R.buffer.moveTo(0, 0);
         R.buffer.font = window.font2;
         R.buffer.trokeStyle = fontStrokeStyle; // 'black';
         R.buffer.lineWidth = 5;
         R.buffer.strokeText(name, option.radius / 2, 8);
         //R.buffer.fillStyle = window.line_color;
         R.buffer.fillStyle = 'white';
         R.buffer.fillText(name, option.radius / 2, 8);

         R.buffer.restore();
      }
   }

   function OnRender() {
      if (!R.dirty) return;
      R.dirty = false;
      
      // clear
      R.buffer.fillStyle = bgColor;
      R.buffer.fillRect(0, 0, R.size.width, R.size.height);
      //R.buffer.clearRect(0, 0, R.size.width, R.size.height);

      if (R.FPS) {
         R.buffer.font = window.font;
         R.buffer.fillStyle = window.line_color;
         R.buffer.fillText(R.FPS + 'FPS', 50, R.center.y - window.radius - 7);
      }

      // shadow
      R.buffer.shadowBlur = 15;
      R.buffer.shadowColor = 'black';
      drawArc({ x: R.center.x, y: R.center.y + 15 + 5, radius: window.radius - 5, rotation: 0, angle: 360, color: bgColor }, '');
      R.buffer.shadowBlur = 0;
      drawArc({ x: R.center.x, y: R.center.y + 15, radius: window.radius, rotation: 0, angle: 360, color: bgColor }, '');

      //
      R.current = null;
      if (R.Items && R.Items.length > 0) {
         R.lastAngle = 0;
         R.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            R.currentAngle = 360 - R.rotation;
            while (R.currentAngle < 0) R.currentAngle += 360;
            while (R.currentAngle >= 360) R.currentAngle -= 360;
            // if (item.angleSum - item.angle <= R.currentAngle && R.currentAngle <= item.angleSum) {
            //    R.current = item.name;
            // }

            drawArc({ x: R.center.x, y: R.center.y + 15, radius: window.radius,
               rotation: R.rotation + R.lastAngle, angle: item.angle, color: item.color }, null, true);
            R.lastAngle += item.angle;
            //if (R.lastAngle >= 360) R.lastAngle -= 360;
         });
         R.lastAngle = 0;
         R.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            R.currentAngle = 360 - R.rotation;
            while (R.currentAngle < 0) R.currentAngle += 360;
            while (R.currentAngle >= 360) R.currentAngle -= 360;
            if (item.angleSum - item.angle <= R.currentAngle && R.currentAngle <= item.angleSum) {
               R.current = item.name;
               R.currentColor = item.color;
            }

            drawArc({ x: R.center.x, y: R.center.y + 15, radius: window.radius,
               rotation: R.rotation + R.lastAngle, angle: item.angle, color: item.color }, item.name, true);
            R.lastAngle += item.angle;
            //if (R.lastAngle >= 360) R.lastAngle -= 360;
         })
         
         //Assigned to an object with two properties: checkedAngle and start, end
         R.checkedAngle = null;
         R.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item.name === R.current) {
            R.checkedAngle = {
               start: item.angleSum - item.angle,
               end: item.angleSum
            };
         }
      });

      } else {
         drawArc({ x: R.center.x, y: R.center.y + 15, radius: window.radius,
            rotation: R.rotation-45, angle: 180, color: getColor(0) }, 'Spin the');
         drawArc({ x: R.center.x, y: R.center.y + 15, radius: window.radius,
            rotation: R.rotation-45+180, angle: 180, color: getColor(1) }, 'Wheel!');
      }
      // pin
      R.buffer.beginPath();
      R.buffer.moveTo(R.size.width / 2    , R.center.y - window.radius + 20);
      R.buffer.lineTo(R.size.width / 2 - 5, R.center.y - window.radius + 5 );
      R.buffer.lineTo(R.size.width / 2 - 5, R.center.y - window.radius + 0 );
      R.buffer.lineTo(R.size.width / 2 + 5, R.center.y - window.radius + 0 );
      R.buffer.lineTo(R.size.width / 2 + 5, R.center.y - window.radius + 5 );
      R.buffer.closePath();
      R.buffer.fillStyle = window.pinColor;
      R.buffer.fill();
      R.buffer.stroke();

      if (R.current) {
         R.buffer.font = window.font;
         if (R.currentColor) {
            R.buffer.strokeStyle = window.line_color; // 'black';
            R.buffer.lineWidth = 5;
            R.buffer.strokeText(R.current, R.size.width / 2, R.center.y - window.radius - 7);
         }
         R.buffer.fillStyle = R.currentColor || window.line_color;
         R.buffer.fillText(R.current, R.size.width / 2, R.center.y - window.radius - 7);
      }
      R.ctx.drawImage(R.bufferCanvas, 0, 0);
   }

   R.Launch = function() {
      var items = $('#items .item');
      var checkedItems = items.filter(isChecked);
      var selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * checkedItems.length);
   
      // Set the winning item
      R.current = $(checkedItems[selectedIndex]).find('.item-title').text();
   
      
      R.launched = true;
      R.angularVelocity = 4 * 360; // 4 * 360;
      R.angularDamping = 0;
      delete R.stopping;
   }


   R.Stop = function() {
      R.stopping = Date.now();
      //R.angularDamping = 360 * (0.5 + 0.1 * Math.random()); // 360 * (2 + Math.random());
      R.angularDamping = 360 * (0.1 + 0.05 * Math.random());
   }

   OnStart();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   Roulette();

   var $result = $('#result');
   var $roll = $('#roll');
   var it;

   R.onStop = function() {
      $result.removeClass('out').text(R.current || 'Spin the wheel!').show().addClass('play');
      clearTimeout(it);
      it = setTimeout(function() {
         $roll.fadeIn(600, function() {
            lock(false);
            $result.hide();
         });
      }, 1500);
   }
});

function lock(b) {
   if (b) {
      $('[contenteditable]').attr('contenteditable', false);
      $('ul').addClass('lock');
   } else {
      $('[contenteditable]').attr('contenteditable', true);
      $('ul').removeClass('lock');
   }
}

//Checkbox!
$(document).on('change', '.item-checkbox', function() {
   // The 'this' keyword refers to the checkbox itself.
   var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
   console.log('Checkbox checked state:', checked);
   
   if (checked) {
       var item = $(this).closest('.item');
       var text = item.find('.item-title').text();
       var index = item.index();
       console.log('Item text:', text);
       console.log('Item index:', index);
   }
});

$(document).on('click', '#roll', function(evt) {
   if (!R.isRolling) {
      R.isRolling = true;
      R.Launch();
      $(evt.currentTarget).focus().addClass('active');
      lock(true);
   } else {
      R.isRolling = false;
      R.Stop();
      $(evt.currentTarget).focus().removeClass('active').hide();
   }
});

$(document).on('click', '.item-delete', function(evt) {
   $(evt.currentTarget).closest('li').remove();
   updateData();
   cleanList();
});



$(document).on('keydown', 'h1[contenteditable]', function(e) {
   if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});

(function() {
   var $t = $('#button-tooltip');
   var $u = $('ul');

   function show() {
      $t.show();
   };
   function hide() {
      $t.hide();
   };
   function move() {
      var o = $u.offset();
      o.top -= 100;
      o.left += 100;
      $t.offset(o);
   };

   $(document).on('mouseenter mousemove', '.item-weight-sub, .item-weight-add', function(e) {
      move();
      show();
   }).on('mouseleave', '.item-weight-sub, .item-weight-add', function(e) {
      hide();
   });

})();
```

[Run screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yumwR.png)

I wanted to implement it so that if you check the box to the right of the 3rd item, the 3rd item will continue to win.

When I press the '시작' button below, the wheel starts rotating, and when I press the 'Stop' button, the wheel starts to slow down, and ultimately I wanted the wheel to stop at my desired location.

```
      if (R.stopping) {
         if (Date.now() - R.stopping > 15 * 1000) {
            R.angularVelocity = 0;
            delete R.stopping;
         }
         else
         {
            // Check if the pin is within the angle range of the checked item
            if (R.checkedAngle && (R.currentAngle < R.checkedAngle.start || R.currentAngle > R.checkedAngle.end)) {
            // If not, keep rotating slowly until you get within the angle
               R.angularVelocity = Math.max(10, R.angularVelocity);
            } else {
            // If within range, roulette stops
               R.angularVelocity -= Math.max(20, Math.min(R.angularVelocity * 0.5, R.angularDamping)) * (R.deltaTime / 1000);
            }
         }
      }
```

So, I wrote the code above so that the pin position stops at the checked item, but it doesn't work properly. I would appreciate some help as to what the problem is.

https://codepen.io/vrywexho-the-lessful/pen/LYaVLap
I have attached js, css, and html code to the link above.
thank you happy new year!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for generally-applicable situations, not really for helping people with specific cases. Can you simplify your problem to form a [mcve], and include that as a Stack Snippet?

Comment: Thank you for letting us know, wizzwizz4. This is my first time using Stack Overflow, so I think I made a mistake because I wasn't familiar with it yet. I will read the link you mentioned and apply it!